# Подскажите корректную архитектуру для программы, которая работает с бд

Tags: c#, sql, .net, office, ms-access

Писал программу, которой на вход подаётся бд access  и выполняются различные преобразования ,и столкнулся с тем, что если поменяется что то во входной структуре бд, то придётся жестко рефакторить код... Дело в том, что я работаю через интероп, в некоторых местах делаю запросы на обновления, которые закодированы в коде, в другом месте, где требуется мощь высокоуровневых языков я открываю recordset и произвожу обновления записей. Можно грузить все в память и работать через datatable, но я побоялся больших баз и отказался от этой затеи... Подскажите, лучше всего уйти от того, что есть к коду, который легко редактировать если структура поменяется, сохраняя высокую скорость обработки.

Comment: "различные преобразования" - это что?

Comment: Ну скажем есть база А, в результате работы получается база Б совершенно другой структурой и набором полей. К полям может быть применена различная логика при работе через рекордсет, например парсинг.

Comment: Реализуйте данную логику через подставку правил в ваш код и тогда Вам не придется всегда изменять свой код для решения данной проблемы. Какие-то правила можно сделать постоянными, какие-то изменяемыми, можно сделать набор правил преобразования.

Comment: можно попробовать сделать некий аналог LiNQ, т.е определить типовые операции с возможностью их кастомизации через передачу функций в качестве параметров, и комбинировать их для получения нужных результатов. Но чтобы сказать что-то конкретнее, нужно знать детали задачи.

Comment: @rdom, задачу я описал чуть выше. Это преобразовать базу вида А в вид Б. В процессе преобразования могут меняться типы полей, добавляться колонки. Парсится(Тут я уже использую обход RecordSet и конструкции C# ) значения в колонках и добавляться в новые колонки.

Comment: вы можете разделить операцию "преобразование базы" на подзадачи, например "добавить столбец в таблицу", "поменять тип столбца" и т.д. и оформить это отдельными методами с необходимыми параметрами, а потом сложить  их в класс-хелпер. И комбинируйте дальше эти методы как вам нравится до получения желаемого результата.

Comment: какого-то универсального абсолютно правильного решения тут не придумать, в любом случае будут какие-то частности, которые придется решать на месте.

Comment: @rdorn, проблема больше в том, что запросы к БД закодированы прямо в коде. Например, изменится название колонки в таблице и мне придется лазить по всему коду и править запросы. Например, если бы я использовал ORM, то я бы мог сразу найти все места в коде, которые необходимо исправить, но, вроде, для Access нет никакого ORM. Хотелось бы как-то облегчить рефакторинг...

Comment: @iluha1810, ну как бы ORM для Access есть у NHibernate, хотя и не из коробки, посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14140727/4269118).

Comment: >проблема больше в том, что запросы к БД закодированы прямо в коде - так задайте значения всех полей/таблиц константами в коде в одном месте. Затем используйте их при построении запросов. Рефакторинг сведётся к изменению значений констант в одном месте.

Comment: @pegoopik, думаю сработает. Правда, так же хотелось бы(по возможности) уйти от запросов в коде программы или к иному виду, который можно контролировать на этапе компиляции. Так как о корректности запросов я могу узнать только во время выполнения программы. Например, я сменил эти константы, но так же где-то поменялся тип=> во время выполнения запроса, какая-нибудь операция не сработает и вылетит с ошибкой. Получается, что все равно придется изучать код изучать и выискивать операции(Правда, в этот раз я буду видеть ссылки на места, где эти константы используются)

Comment: @iluxa1810 а про шаблоны DTO & DAO не слышали?

Answer (score 2):

Создать в БД таблицу с конфигом базы. И сходя из этого формировать SQL-запросы. Например, создаём таблицу info описанием таблиц.

```
CREATE TABLE info
(
    ID int identity (1, 1) primary key
    ,NameTable varchar(50)
    ,NameColumn varchar(50)
)
```

При запуске приложения читаем эту таблицу, и формируем запросы для других таблиц. Например загружаем таблицу в DataTable c именем infoTable:

```
string command = "SELECT [ID] ";
foreach (DataRow row in infoTable.Rows)
{
    command = command + ",[" + row[2].ToString() + "]";
}
command = command + " FROM [" + row[1].ToString() + "]";
```

В итоге в command получается запрос типа:

```
SELECT [ID], [NameColumn1], [NameColumn2] FROM [NameTable]
```

И так далее... Меняется таблица в БД, меняем описание, запросы формируются иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант изменить программу таким образом чтобы она только выполняла  внешние скрипты (в виде файликов `001_update_table1.sql`), которые вы будите при необходимости редактировать. В таком случае:

- Вам не будет необходимости все время пересобирать и переписывать реализацию программы.
- Можно реализовать поддержку различные версии БД.
- Правки в одном месте (только в скриптах), не нужно выискивать переменные в DataSet'ах иди захардкоженых переменных.

Answer (score 1):

А может быть на входе подавать не только бд, а и пакет изменений. 
Структуру которая будет описывать такой список изменений можно уже разработать в зависимости от поставленных задач.

Таким образом при изменении бд вам не нужно будет редактировать код, а только файл с необходимыми изменениями.